# java mail aws smtp: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 220 Ready to start TLS

Tags: java, logging, log4j, amazon-ses, smtpappender

I have configured the below properties for smtp appender. the same configuration works fine in local but getting error on AWS

```
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=20
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=<username>
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=<password>
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPort=587
log4j.appender.email.From=<from@email>
log4j.appender.email.To=<to@email>
log4j.appender.email.Subject=<Subjec>
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] (%c{1}:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.email.SMTPDebug=true
log4j.appender.email.EnableSsl=true
log4j.appender.email.smtp.starttls.enable=true
log4j.appender.email.smtp.auth=true
log4j.appender.email.TLS=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I have used 1.6.4 version for mailapi and smtp jars.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

on

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to pass through this error simply by adding the following JVM properties :

> -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
> -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
> -Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2